# Haskell Time Limit on Evaluation

Tags: haskell, time

Does anyone know of a function that will allow only a certain amount of time to execute a function. Something with a type signature like this.

```
limited::Int->(a->b)->a->IO (Maybe b)
```

I can't think of how to implement, and I couldn't find it. The reason why I ask is I am going to make a list of all possible [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) programs, and I want to filter out the ones that take too long.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's [a dedicated function](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=timeout) from System.Timeout:

```
timeout :: Int -> IO a -> IO (Maybe a)
```

To have it the way you wrote, just use

```
limited t f x = timeout t $ do
     let y = f x
     y `seq` return y
```

Remember that Haskell's laziness means any value is what other languages might call "memoised function of zero arguments", so you don't really need the `(a->b) -> a ->`.

Comment: I had no idea that existed.

Comment: `limited t f x = timeout t (return $! f x)`

Comment: Better yet: `timeout t $ evaluate (f x)` (`evaluate` is defined in `Control.Exception`)

Answer (score 11):

Using the `async` package we can `race` threads.

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.Async

limited :: Int -> (a -> b) -> a -> IO (Maybe a)
limited n f a = isLeft <$> race (return $! f a) (threadDelay n)
  where isLeft (Left a) = Just a
        isLeft _        = Nothing
```

`race` runs two `IO` computations in separate threads and returns whichever one "wins", so we just race our thread against a `threadDelay`.

Note that we use `($!)` to `seq` the result `f a`. If we don't then the `Left` thread always wins and the computation actually occurs in the main thread when you look at it.