# Haskell functions which time out

Tags: multithreading, haskell, io, timeout

```
import Math.NumberTheory.Primes (factorise)
import System.Timeout (timeout)
import Control.Monad (liftM)

type RetType = [(Integer, Int)] -- factorise's return type

-- proposed function
timedFact :: Integer -> Integer -> Either RetType Integer
timedFact u n = ?
```

Trying to understand how to write a wrapper function for factorise which times out after u usec.  If it succeeds it returns `RetType` otherwise it returns `Integer` (what was passed in)

I'm kind of new to Haskell.  I understand a timeout requires working in the `IO` Monad but I'm having trouble pulling back the appropriate result.  (Note: I'm not married to `Either`.  `Maybe RetType` would be fine, too).

Thanks for any help

Comment: You might also be interested in: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/speculation

Comment: cf. [Haskell Time Limit on Evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752083/haskell-time-limit-on-evaluation).

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the type, `timeout :: Int -> IO a -> IO (Maybe a)`, it could be used as

```
import Math.NumberTheory.Primes (factorise)
import System.Timeout (timeout)
import Control.Exception (evaluate)
import Control.DeepSeq (force)

timedFact :: Int -> Integer -> IO (Maybe [(Integer, Int)])
timedFact u = 
      timeout u . evaluate . force . factorise
```

Testing:

```
 #> timedFact 3000000 1231231231223234234273434343469494949494499437141
Nothing
(3.04 secs, 2639142736 bytes)

 #> timedFact 4000000 1231231231223234234273434343469494949494499437141
Just [(1009,1),(47729236307,1),(125199345589541,1),(204202903382078984027,1)]
(3.07 secs, 2662489296 bytes)
```

*update:* as *user2407038* [says in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878244/haskell-functions-which-time-out/32878368?noredirect=1#comment53589782_32878368) (thanks!),

```
timedFact u n = timeout u (return $!! factorise n)
```

also works. `($!!)` comes from `Control.DeepSeq` too. To quote the docs, [*"In the expression f $!! x, x is fully evaluated before the function f is applied to it"*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.4.1.2/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html#v:-36--33--33-).

Comment: I think you'd have to force the evaluation of `x`, otherwise the evaluation happens outside of `timeout`.

Comment: `force` evaluates to normal form. Do you really need `evaluate` after it?

Comment: @user2407038 I tried putting `return` there but it didn't bail out.

Comment: @user2407038 cf. https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/beginners/2010-April/004023.html

Comment: @user2407038, while `evaluate x` looks a lot like `return $! x`, it turns out that there are important but subtle differences. Subtle enough to have confused some of the lead GHC implementers; important enough to have led to a special `seq#` primop just to define `evaluate` properly.

Comment: @WillNess @dfeuer `return $!! factorise v` works. `\u v -> timeout u $ return $ let r = factorise v in r \`deepseq\` r` doesn't work and is equivalent to `force (return r)`. However, `\u v -> timeout u $ let r = factorise v in r \`deepseq\` return r` does work and is equivalent to `return $!! r`. The `evaluate` is truly unnecessary but since the value is already evaluated when evaluate is called, I doubt it has any overhead, so it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Please ignore the above comment it was incomplete .  Here's the full one:

Thanks, Will. This is about as far as I got actually doing something slightly different.  I am interested in pulling the underlying result back from IO as well. If I write in ghci:

let x = timedFact 4000000   1231231231223234234273434343469494949494499437141

:t x -- gives
x :: IO (Maybe [(Integer, Int)])

How would I pull back the underlying value?  I tried readIORef in a do clause but that didn't work for me.

Thanks for your help, folks

Comment: Ah, unsafePerformIO (gulp) is what I'm looking for. 

Do you think if I had several of these "timedFacts" running in parallel that there's a chance for corrupion, etc?

Comment: you pull the values in a do block, like this: `do { x <- timedFact 40 40; case x of Nothing -> ... ; Just factorization -> ... use factorization ... }`.

Comment: @user3424410 1) You know that you can delete comments? 2) I strongly advise against `unsafePerformIO`. There *is* a reason why it has `unsafe` in its name. Whenever you use it you should provide a proof that it wont cause troubles.  If you aren't able to do that you should simply avoid using it because you can mess things up pretty easily. Simply use `timedFact` as any other `IO` action.

Comment: Thanks, deleted.

Thinking about this some more.  The better way to go about this is to slightly extend the library to be able to configure the number of elliptical curves attempted.

Comment: @user3424410 This is a terrible place to use `unsafePerformIO`: there is no reason to believe that running a pure computation twice will take the same amount of time (hence either hit or miss the timeout) both times. There's tons of variables involved, including: which thunks have been forced so far; which reads hit in the cache and which don't; how your computation/watchdog threads interact with the OS' scheduler; and many others.

Comment: @DanielWagner: Of course, there's no reason to believe that and I didn't give any indication I would expect that.  Besides, I already responded about using a different (wiser) tack.

There's a practical need (which as I said I can replace by modifying the underlying library)   The initial thinking was that if I had a large number I needed to factor, I could specify an upper bound on the time, be it a day or 5 minutes, to factor it.  Any unfactored piece could be marked composite.   Anyways, that was the original thinking.

Thanks everyone for setting me on the right track.